# How do I make ASWD keyboard movement control

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard

I have started to learn some Microsoft.DirectX 3D basic techniques, and bumped to this problem that is too dificult for me. I have created 3D Scene, Camera, Light's etc, with some simple 3D objects drawn. What I want to do now is simple 3D rotation of that objects around all three axes. For that I want to use Arrow and ASWD keyboard keys as in manner in computer games are used. For that I have used OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp event handlers :

```
#region - Event handler -
    protected override void   OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnKeyDown(e);


        #region - speed -
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Add || e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Oemplus)
            step_p = true;
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Subtract || e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.OemMinus)
            step_m = true;

        if(step_p)
            step++;
        if(step_m)
            step--;

        if(step==0)
            step = 1;
        #endregion


        #region - rotation -
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = true;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = true;
        }

        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            a = true;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            d = true;
        }


        if(left)
            angleZ_D+=step;
        if(right)
            angleZ_D-=step;
        if(up)
            angleX_D-=step;
        if(down)
            angleX_D+=step;
        if(a)
            angleY_D+=step;
        if(d)
            angleY_D-=step;

        //
        //
        //
        if(angleX_D == 360)
            angleX_D = 0;
        if(angleY_D >= 360)
            angleY_D = 0;
        if(angleZ_D >= 360)
            angleZ_D = 0;


        angleX_R = angleX_D * rad;
        angleY_R = angleY_D * rad;
        angleZ_R = angleZ_D * rad;
        //
        //
        //
        #endregion


        #region - zoom -
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.W)
        {
            w = true;
        }
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.S)
        {
            s = true;
        }

        if(w)
        {
            zoom+=0.1f * step;

            if(zoom>10.0f) zoom=10.0f;
        }

        if(s)
        {

            zoom-=0.1f * step;

            if(zoom<1.0f) zoom=1.0f;
        }
        #endregion

        Draw();
    }


    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);

        #region - speed -
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Add || e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Oemplus)
            step_p = false;
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Subtract || e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.OemMinus)
            step_m = false;
        #endregion


        #region - rotation -
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = false;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = false;
        }

        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            a = false;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            d = false;
        }
        #endregion


        #region - zoom -
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.W)
        {
            w = false;
        }
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.S)
        {
            s = false;
        }
        #endregion

        Draw();
    }
```

**This is the problem :**

When I press key <kbd>A</kbd> and while holding it down I press key <kbd>W</kbd>, program works perfectly but when I release key <kbd>W</kbd> the event handler do not recognize that key <kbd>A</kbd> is still pressed.

Is there solution for such problem in C# 4.0 and .Net framework 2.0

All the best,
Željko Perić

According to

> Quote:
>       You are depending on the keyboard repeating a key when held down.
>       That stops working as soon as you press another key.
>       You instead need to use a Timer and in the Tick event handler
>       check which way you want to move. Now key-repeat no longer matters.
>       Set the timer's Interval property to 15 or 31 to get good consistency. – [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

this is problem solution :

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WASD_keyboard_game_control
    {
        public partial class MainForm : Form
        {

            //
            // Global variables declaration
            //

            //
            // Timer
            //
            // Implements a timer that
            // raises event at user defined interval
            //
            Timer Clock;

            //
            // Set Timer tick Interval in miliseconds
            //
            // By changing value of Interval,
            // we control how often the timer tick event handler is raised
            // and eventually the call frequency of Main_Function()
            //
            const int Interval = 15;

            //
            // Variables for counting the number
            // of times that program has confirmed
            // the key down state of AWSD keys
            //
            int W = 0;
            int A = 0;
            int S = 0;
            int D = 0;

            //
            // Variables ( flags ) for memorizing
            // the key down state of AWSD keys
            //
            // true  - key is down ( pressed )
            //
            // false - key is up ( released )
            //
            //
            bool w = false;
            bool a = false;
            bool s = false;
            bool d = false;

            //
            //
            //

            public MainForm()
            {
                //
                // The InitializeComponent() call is required
                // for Windows Forms designer support.
                //
                InitializeComponent();

                //
                // Call Initialize_Timer() function
                //
                Initialize_Timer();
            }


            void Initialize_Timer()
            {
                // Create new timer
                Clock = new Timer();

                // Set timer tick interval in miliseconds
                //
                // By changing value of interval,
                // we control how often the timer tick event handler is raised
                // and eventually the call frequency of Main_Function()
                //
                Clock.Interval = Interval;

                //
                // Add timer tick event handler
                //
                // This event handler is raised
                // every time timer make tick
                //
                // The smaler value for timer interval,
                // more often the event handler is raised
                //
                Clock.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.ClockTick);

                //
                // Start timer
                //
                Clock.Start();
            }


            void ClockTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //
                // Timer tick event handler
                //

                //
                // Call Main_Function()
                //
                Main_Function();

                //
                //
                //
            }


            protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                //
                // This event handler is raised every time
                // some key on the keyboard is first pressed
                //

                base.OnKeyDown(e);

                //
                // Set corresponding key down flag state to true
                //

                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
                    w = true;
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                    a = true;
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                    s = true;
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                    d = true;
            }


            protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                //
                // This event handler is raised every time
                // some key on the keyboard is released
                //

                base.OnKeyUp(e);

                //
                // Set corresponding key down flag state to false
                //

                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
                    w = false;
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                    a = false;
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                    s = false;
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                    d = false;
            }


            void Main_Function()
            {
                //
                // Main function
                //

                //
                // This function is called every time the
                // timer tick event handler is raised
                //

                //
                // This function determines wich key is pressed
                // upon key down flag value and updates correspondig counter value
                // 
                // Counter value shows how many times program has confirmed the
                // key down state and not how many times user has pressed the key
                //


                //
                // Increase counter value if key is down
                //
                if(a)
                    A++;
                if(s)
                    S++;
                if(w)
                    W++;
                if(d)
                    D++;

                //
                // Show values of counters
                //
                Label_A.Text = "A = " + A.ToString();
                Label_S.Text = "S = " + S.ToString();
                Label_W.Text = "W = " + W.ToString();
                Label_D.Text = "D = " + D.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `A` key instead of `Q` key?

Comment: Thanks @PaviełKraskoŭski it is A

Comment: You are depending on the keyboard repeating a key when held down.  That stops working as soon as you press another key.  You instead need to use a Timer and in the Tick event handler check which way you want to move.  Now key-repeat no longer matters.  Set the timer's Interval property to 15 or 31 to get good consistency.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant your solution works excellent.